# Python POST XML not executed

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

The Headers post fine but the associated XML seems to be taken as string data only, XML is not processed.
XML string is of the form:

```
params = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding"="UTF-8 "?>
<MainRequest>
<requestEnvelope><errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
</requestEnvelope></MainRequest>'''
```

The POST is of the form:

```
enc_params = urllib.quote(params)
request = urllib2.Request("https://myURL/",enc_params, headers)
```

The send of the XML is of the form:

```
%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%22%3D%22UTF-8%20%22%3F%3E%0A%3CMainReq
uest%3E%0A%3CrequestEnvelope%3E%3CerrorLanguage%3Een_US%3C/errorLanguage%3E%0A%3
C/requestEnvelope%3E
```

The error message then indicates XML content is missing.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: XML **Is** "string data". Do you have access to the server side? Can you examine the logs?

I also notice a syntax error in your processing instruction at `encoding"="UTF-8 "`

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding a content-type header?  To tell the server your request is XML, add the following before sending the request:

```
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the 'encoding', the removal of the 'urllib.quote' and the 'Content-Type' header comments got me through. I have working Python/XML Postings.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the "urllib.quote()" call. That's what created the string which starts "%3C%3Fxml". If you want to POST XML then just send that XML string as the data, along with the Content-Type that ataylor mentioned. (But in most cases that doesn't make a difference.)